# Cisco 200 series switches with SonicWALL NSA 4600 setting up VLAN

Tags: cisco, routing, vlan, sonicwall, lan

Does anyone know how to setup VLANs and make them communicate using a SonicWALL 4600.

**On the Cisco SG200-50P switch:**

For example, I have 3 SG200-50P Cisco switches. Say I want to create a VLAN for our VoIP. I create a VLAN and give it a VLAN ID and name. Then, I assign the ports I want on that VLAN as untagged correct? For example, if I want ports 31-40, I set them all as untagged? Also, by default they're all on trunk mode, I should select access mode right?

After I'm done with setting all the ports, do I have to keep the ports connected to the other switches in trunk mode and set them to untagged, tagged, etc?

**On the SonicWALL:**

After I create the VLANs on the switches, in order to communicate between VLANs, I have to add interfaces. I create a new zone etc pretty much like in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1C9UoE4TRes

Now the question is how do I communicate between the two. Yes, I will have now created VLANs on both, but how do I communicate when I keep creating VLANs and need them to communicate, etc. Pretty much, I'm going to use the SonicWALL to do the routing.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, a bunch of answers.  Here we go:

For the VoIP VLAN - will the PCs be sharing the switch ports on the back of the phone?  If so, you'll need to set the switch ports as **tagged trunk** ports, and configure the phone for the VLAN.  Otherwise, you can do as you stated.  The phones will connect to the switch on **untagged access** ports. The ports between switches and to the SonicWALL will be **tagged trunk** ports.

For the SonicWALL, you'll create a separate zone for each VLAN. Configure the VLAN interfaces with the proper VLAN ID, and it should work (as long as the SonicWALL is plugged into a **tagged trunk** port.

Give it a shot and let us know if you run into any problems.

Comment: I tried it today at the office. Except when I tried to put the ports between switches and to the sonicwall to tagged, since they were already trunk, everyone connected to that switch went down. One thing to note, however, is that I selected tagged on port vlan 1 not vlan 10 the one I created. Was that how it was suppose to be or should I have done everything we talked about on the newly created vlan? And would I have had to change all the other trunks to tagged on all the other switches since they are all interconnected? Only one switch(trunk) eventually goes to the sonicwall.

Comment: You need to tag the switch->Sonicwall port for each VLAN it carries.  So, if you have VLAN 1 for default LAN, VLAN 10 for VOIP, and VLAN 20 for something else, the port needs to be a trunk tagged for all three VLANs.  Same goes for trunk ports between switches (unless you purposely want to exclude a switch from a VLAN).